# Firebase Firestore doc.data() doesn't return anything

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I'm implementing a firebase function that takes metadata from a store in firestore, then get all files of that store folder in storage and compares this data with the one stored in the metadata. If some condition applies it sends an email to indicate that theres a possible incident to attend.

It was working just fine. However, since I added the Firebase trigger mail extension it crashed. Now, when I call the doc.data() function in order to get the data from a document, it returns empty, and I can't get the files count from storage anymore.

This is the code I use atm:

```
const db = getFirestore();
const bucket = getStorage().bucket();

exports.checkSanity = onSchedule(
  { schedule: "every 1 minutes", memory: "4GiB" },
  async (event) => {
    const subwayRef = db.collection("subway");
    const snapshot = await subwayRef.get();

    logger.log("snapshot: ", snapshot);

    const docs = [];

    snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      docs.push(doc);
      logger.log("doc: ", doc);
    });

    // array of stores to notify
    let toNotifyFail = [];
    let toNotifySuccess = [];
    for (const doc of docs) {
      const data = doc.data();
      logger.log("data: ", data);

      const {
        id,
        name,
        openHour,
        closeHour,
        status,
        notified,
        lastTotalCount,
      } = data;

      const docRef = db.collection("subway").doc(id);

      logger.log("[INFO] Showing stores configs");
      logger.log(
        `${doc.id} => ${data.name}, ${data.openHour}, ${data.closeHour}, ${data.status}, ${data.notified}, ${data.notified_at}, ${data.lastTotalCount}`
      );

      logger.log("before");
      // get last bucket total count
      const [files] = await bucket.getFiles({ prefix: `${name}` });
      logger.log("after...");

      logger.log(`${name} => contains ${files.length}`);

      if (lastTotalCount != 0) {
        // get current hour
        const date = new Date();
        if (
          true /*date.getHours() >= openHour && date.getHours() < closeHour*/
        ) {
          if (!notified && lastTotalCount == files.length) {
            // update store
            await docRef.update({
              notified: true,
              notified_at: date.toString(),
              status: "paused",
            });

            // add to notifications email
            toNotifyFail.push(`<li>${name}</li>`);
          }

          // store back to normal
          if (notified && lastTotalCount < files.length) {
            // update store
            await docRef.update({
              notified: false,
              notified_at: date.toString(),
              status: "capturing",
            });

            toNotifySuccess.push(`<li>${name}</li>`);
          }
        }
      }

      await docRef.update({
        lastTotalCount: files.length,
      });
    }

    // notify
    if (toNotifyFail.length > 0) {
      await db.collection("mail").add({
        to: ["***", "****"],
        message: {
          subject: "Nuevo fallo detectado en subway-counting",
          text: "Se ha detectado un nuevo fallo en una o mas tiendas",
          html: `Las siguientes tiendas han dejado de enviar datos: <br> <ul>${toNotifyFail.join()}</ul>`,
        },
      });
    }

    if (toNotifySuccess.length > 0) {
      await db.collection("mail").add({
        to: ["***", "***"],
        message: {
          subject: "Nuevo fix en subway-counting",
          text: "Una o mas tiendas han vuelto a funcionar con normalidad",
          html: `Las siguientes tiendas han vuelto a enviar datos: <br> <ul>${toNotifySuccess.join()}</ul>`,
        },
      });
    }
  }
);
```

And the error I get from the logger is:

```
Error: Value for argument "documentPath" is not a valid resource path. Path must be a non-empty string.
    at entryFromArgs (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/logger/index.js:130:19)
    at Object.error (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/logger/index.js:116:11)
    at httpFunc (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/v2/providers/scheduler.js:71:20)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

Most surely because I'm not sending any value as prefix to the storage, or the id to set the docs ref, since data is empty as doc.data() is not returning anything.

Any clue on why this is happening now? Any help would be much appreciated!

UPDATE: this is what I get from the logs:

```
INFO 2023-11-19T05:43:00.503799Z snapshot: QuerySnapshot { _query: CollectionReference { _firestore: Firestore { _settings: [Object], _settingsFrozen: true, _serializer: [Serializer], _projectId: 'photo-capture-11c8e', _databaseId: '(default)', registeredListenersCount: 0, bulkWritersCount: 0, _backoffSettings: [Object], _clientPool: [ClientPool], _gax: [Object] }, _queryOptions: QueryOptions { parentPath: [ResourcePath], collectionId: 'subway', converter: [Object], allDescendants: false, filters: [], fieldOrders: [], startAt: undefined, endAt: undefined, limit: undefined, limitType: undefined, offset: undefined, projection: undefined, kindless: false, requireConsistency: true }, _serializer: Serializer { createReference: [Function (anonymous)], createInteger: [Function (anonymous)], allowUndefined: false }, _allowUndefined: false }, _readTime: Timestamp { _seconds: 1700372580, _nanoseconds: 490801000 }, _size: 5, _materializedDocs: null, _materializedChanges: null, _docs: [Function (anonymous)], _changes: [Function (anonymous)] }
INFO 2023-11-19T05:43:00.504023Z doc: QueryDocumentSnapshot { _fieldsProto: { closeHour: { integerValue: '23', valueType: 'integerValue' }, notified: { booleanValue: false, valueType: 'booleanValue' }, name: { stringValue: 'subway-merced', valueType: 'stringValue' }, openHour: { integerValue: '7', valueType: 'integerValue' }, notified_at: { stringValue: '', valueType: 'stringValue' }, status: { stringValue: 'capturing', valueType: 'stringValue' }, lastTotalCount: { integerValue: '0', valueType: 'integerValue' } }, _ref: DocumentReference { _firestore: Firestore { _settings: [Object], _settingsFrozen: true, _serializer: [Serializer], _projectId: 'photo-capture-11c8e', _databaseId: '(default)', registeredListenersCount: 0, bulkWritersCount: 0, _backoffSettings: [Object], _clientPool: [ClientPool], _gax: [Object] }, _path: QualifiedResourcePath { segments: [Array], projectId: 'photo-capture-11c8e', databaseId: '(default)' }, _converter: { toFirestore: [Function: toFirestore], fromFirestore: [Function: fromFirestore] } }, _serializer: Serializer { createReference: [Function (anonymous)], createInteger: [Function (anonymous)], allowUndefined: false }, _readTime: Timestamp { _seconds: 1700372580, _nanoseconds: 490801000 }, _createTime: Timestamp { _seconds: 1700372192, _nanoseconds: 562519000 }, _updateTime: Timestamp { _seconds: 1700372192, _nanoseconds: 562519000 } }
INFO 2023-11-19T05:43:00.504232Z doc: QueryDocumentSnapshot { _fieldsProto: { closeHour: { integerValue: '19', valueType: 'integerValue' }, notified: { booleanValue: false, valueType: 'booleanValue' }, name: { stringValue: 'subway-tenderini', valueType: 'stringValue' }, openHour: { integerValue: '9', valueType: 'integerValue' }, notified_at: { stringValue: '', valueType: 'stringValue' }, lastTotalCount: { integerValue: '0', valueType: 'integerValue' }, status: { stringValue: 'capturing', valueType: 'stringValue' } }, _ref: DocumentReference { _firestore: Firestore { _settings: [Object], _settingsFrozen: true, _serializer: [Serializer], _projectId: 'photo-capture-11c8e', _databaseId: '(default)', registeredListenersCount: 0, bulkWritersCount: 0, _backoffSettings: [Object], _clientPool: [ClientPool], _gax: [Object] }, _path: QualifiedResourcePath { segments: [Array], projectId: 'photo-capture-11c8e', databaseId: '(default)' }, _converter: { toFirestore: [Function: toFirestore], fromFirestore: [Function: fromFirestore] } }, _serializer: Serializer { createReference: [Function (anonymous)], createInteger: [Function (anonymous)], allowUndefined: false }, _readTime: Timestamp { _seconds: 1700372580, _nanoseconds: 490801000 }, _createTime: Timestamp { _seconds: 1700372408, _nanoseconds: 635977000 }, _updateTime: Timestamp { _seconds: 1700372408, _nanoseconds: 635977000 } }
INFO 2023-11-19T05:43:00.504424Z doc: QueryDocumentSnapshot { _fieldsProto: { closeHour: { integerValue: '20', valueType: 'integerValue' }, notified: { booleanValue: false, valueType: 'booleanValue' }, openHour: { integerValue: '10', valueType: 'integerValue' }, notified_at: { stringValue: '', valueType: 'stringValue' }, ' name': { stringValue: 'subway-mall-del-centro', valueType: 'stringValue' }, lastTotalCount: { integerValue: '0', valueType: 'integerValue' }, status: { stringValue: 'capturing', valueType: 'stringValue' } }, _ref: DocumentReference { _firestore: Firestore { _settings: [Object], _settingsFrozen: true, _serializer: [Serializer], _projectId: 'photo-capture-11c8e', _databaseId: '(default)', registeredListenersCount: 0, bulkWritersCount: 0, _backoffSettings: [Object], _clientPool: [ClientPool], _gax: [Object] }, _path: QualifiedResourcePath { segments: [Array], projectId: 'photo-capture-11c8e', databaseId: '(default)' }, _converter: { toFirestore: [Function: toFirestore], fromFirestore: [Function: fromFirestore] } }, _serializer: Serializer { createReference: [Function (anonymous)], createInteger: [Function (anonymous)], allowUndefined: false }, _readTime: Timestamp { _seconds: 1700372580, _nanoseconds: 490801000 }, _createTime: Timestamp { _seconds: 1700372324, _nanoseconds: 62497000 }, _updateTime: Timestamp { _seconds: 1700372324, _nanoseconds: 62497000 } }
INFO 2023-11-19T05:43:00.504649Z doc: QueryDocumentSnapshot { _fieldsProto: { closeHour: { integerValue: '22', valueType: 'integerValue' }, notified: { booleanValue: false, valueType: 'booleanValue' }, name: { stringValue: 'subway-subcentro', valueType: 'stringValue' }, openHour: { integerValue: '7', valueType: 'integerValue' }, notified_at: { stringValue: '', valueType: 'stringValue' }, status: { stringValue: 'capturing', valueType: 'stringValue' }, lastTotalCount: { integerValue: '0', valueType: 'integerValue' } }, _ref: DocumentReference { _firestore: Firestore { _settings: [Object], _settingsFrozen: true, _serializer: [Serializer], _projectId: 'photo-capture-11c8e', _databaseId: '(default)', registeredListenersCount: 0, bulkWritersCount: 0, _backoffSettings: [Object], _clientPool: [ClientPool], _gax: [Object] }, _path: QualifiedResourcePath { segments: [Array], projectId: 'photo-capture-11c8e', databaseId: '(default)' }, _converter: { toFirestore: [Function: toFirestore], fromFirestore: [Function: fromFirestore] } }, _serializer: Serializer { createReference: [Function (anonymous)], createInteger: [Function (anonymous)], allowUndefined: false }, _readTime: Timestamp { _seconds: 1700372580, _nanoseconds: 490801000 }, _createTime: Timestamp { _seconds: 1700162127, _nanoseconds: 183785000 }, _updateTime: Timestamp { _seconds: 1700163583, _nanoseconds: 355554000 } }
INFO 2023-11-19T05:43:00.504812Z doc: QueryDocumentSnapshot { _fieldsProto: { name: { stringValue: 'subway-los-militares', valueType: 'stringValue' }, lastTotalCount: { integerValue: '0', valueType: 'integerValue' }, notified: { booleanValue: false, valueType: 'booleanValue' }, status: { stringValue: 'capturing', valueType: 'stringValue' }, closeHour: { integerValue: '19', valueType: 'integerValue' }, openHour: { integerValue: '8', valueType: 'integerValue' }, notified_at: { stringValue: '', valueType: 'stringValue' } }, _ref: DocumentReference { _firestore: Firestore { _settings: [Object], _settingsFrozen: true, _serializer: [Serializer], _projectId: 'photo-capture-11c8e', _databaseId: '(default)', registeredListenersCount: 0, bulkWritersCount: 0, _backoffSettings: [Object], _clientPool: [ClientPool], _gax: [Object] }, _path: QualifiedResourcePath { segments: [Array], projectId: 'photo-capture-11c8e', databaseId: '(default)' }, _converter: { toFirestore: [Function: toFirestore], fromFirestore: [Function: fromFirestore] } }, _serializer: Serializer { createReference: [Function (anonymous)], createInteger: [Function (anonymous)], allowUndefined: false }, _readTime: Timestamp { _seconds: 1700372580, _nanoseconds: 490801000 }, _createTime: Timestamp { _seconds: 1700369879, _nanoseconds: 916393000 }, _updateTime: Timestamp { _seconds: 1700370052, _nanoseconds: 698090000 } }
INFO 2023-11-19T05:43:00.505032Z data:
```

UPDATE 2: JSON.stringify(data) returns:

```
data:  {"closeHour":23,"notified":false,"name":"subway-merced","openHour":7,"notified_at":"","status":"capturing","lastTotalCount":0}
```

Comment: Have you added some console.log() statements to see the values of the paths you are passing? It appears that something has changed and you are now passing an empty string to the path some where... What you can do is try to remove or ignore every path that is empty... Depending on what you find in your log statements should tell you a lot about what is going on... If you still can't figure out what's up then you can update your question with some of these logs (or examples of them) and I'll try to help further.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply! I added the output from the logs as requested

Comment: Alright very very interesting, so your first document line from the logs (i.e. the second line) is the document in question. Worst case scenario you should be able to retrieve the values from the doc directly if this function doesn't work... I'm curious if you changed the line to `logger.log("data: ", JSON.stringify(data));` What that line would look like. I'm quite confused if data is an empty string and why it would be?

Comment: Looks like it returns the string notation of the object, very weird

Comment: Okay so your error most certainly comes from this line `const docRef = db.collection("subway").doc(id);` And because of the logs we have identified the problem as well. there is no id attribute in data, therefore it is undefined... so your code really is `const docRef = db.collection("subway").doc(undefined);`. As you can imagine that's a problem. I'm not sure how to fix it (If I'm honest, I've never used firebase), but you will want to figure out how to find the appropriate id.

Comment: Yeah, it came from that. The thing was I was getting the id from doc.data(), but the id comes directly from the doc. So replacing ```const docRef = db.collection("subway").doc(id);``` by ```const docRef = db.collection("subway").doc(doc.id);``` made it

Comment: So it's fixed? If so awesome glad :)